# Trying to run simple JenkinsFile getting 403 forbidden error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run a simple JenkinsFile

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {

                sh 'java -version'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing..'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there isn't much here. But I am getting a forbidden error even though I configured an account which is the owner of the repository. I posted the error as-it-is just changed the `username/repository` to `my-account/my-repo`

```
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/my-account/my-repo.git # timeout=10
Fetching without tags
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/my-account/my-repo.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Pull Request Builder
 > git fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/my-account/my-repo.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/my-account/my-repo.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:817)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1084)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1115)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:109)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:73)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:221)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/my-account/my-repo.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/my-account/my-repo.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1924)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1643)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:352)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:815)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: how are your git credentials in jenkins?  are you doing username and password, or github ssh key?

Comment: paste your git repo configuration (could be a snapshot picture), so people can understand quickly

Comment: Did you solve this issue ??? I'm facing the same issue ??

Comment: @rohitthomas No. Did not solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to switch to SSH when checking out the code.(Easier and always works)

If switching is not an option, then use username/password or better, generate a secret key and use that to access your repo.

Since your using it for Pull Request I'm guessing `checkout scm`, if this is case by default it will use https- which failed for me using 403, unfortunately the issue lied with my git being an old version 1.7/1.8 not sure exactly. Upgrading it worked like a charm :)

Hope it helps :)